# Ordering a list with 3 model objects

Tags: python, django

I've got 3 queryset's: `Post`, `Two` and `AdvertisePost`.

The way it currently works is: my site is paginated to have 14 objects on every page. Of those 14 objects it is ordered like this:

```
1. Post
2. Post
3. Post
4. Post
5. Two
6. Post
7. Post
8. Post
9. Post
10.Two
11.Post
12.Post
13.Post
14.Post
```

But I would now like to have an `AdvertisePost` on the 12th slot of every page. Not to replace the `Post` on the 12th slot, but to push it down. But not to push it down so that it ruins the formation of the next page.

Here's my current code:

```
two_list = []
returned_list = []

two = Two.objects.all()

for i in two:
    two_list.append(i)

ads = AdvertisePost.objects.all()

posts = Post.objects.all()

for n, post in enumerate(posts):
    returned_list.append(post)
    if len(two_list) > 0 and (n + 1) % 4 == 0 and len(returned_list) % 14 != 0:
        returned_list.append(two_list.pop(0))

paginator = Paginator(returned_list, 14)
page = request.GET.get('page')

try:
    lst = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    lst = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    lst = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Any idea how I can fit an `AdvertisePost` object on every 12th slot of every page?

**EDIT**

The following code starts off with 5 posts instead of 4. After that the formation works fine (the posts are in batches of 4).

```
for number in range(all_count):
    if number % 5 == 0 and len(two_list) and number != 0:
        answer.append(two_list.pop())
    elif number % 12 == 0 and len(ads) and number != 0:
        answer.append(ads.pop())
    elif len(posts):
        answer.append(posts.pop())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
two = list(Two.objects.all())

ads = list(AdvertisePost.objects.all())

posts = list(Post.objects.all())

all_count = len(posts) + len(ads) + len(two)
answer = []

for i in range(all_count+1):
    number = i % 14
    if number % 5 == 4 and len(two):
        answer.append(two.pop())
    elif number % 12 == 11 and len(ads):
        answer.append(ads.pop())
    elif len(posts):
        answer.append(posts.pop())
    elif len(two):
        answer.append(two.pop())
    elif len(ads):
        answer.append(ads.pop())
```

After that, you should paginate answer and return the paginated answer. I think this way is simpler. In the and you can not add

```
elif len(ads):
    answer.append(ads.pop())
```

if you may have many ads and few posts or two

Comment: I've just tried this code - the list starts with `Two` and not `Post`. So it goes `Two, Post, Post, Post, Post, Two, Post, Post, Post, Post, Two, Post, AdvertisePost, Post`. The order seems to be correct but it just needs a minor tweak so it starts with `Post, Post, Post, Post, Two, Post...` etc. Any idea?

Comment: @Zorgan you are getting `Two` at first place, because when loop execute for first time `number` variable will be 0 and the first `if` condition will be passed as 0%5 will always be 0. you can add one more if condition at top for checking `if number==0:`

Comment: @Satendra i've tried adding that if condition, and that fixes the problem. But it also makes the list start with 5 posts instead of 4. After the first batch of 5, the formation works fine (batches of 4 posts). Any idea why this is and how I can fix it? (I've added my code in my edit)

Comment: do one thing remove `number != 0` condition, and start the loop from 1 itself, `for number in range(1, all_count+1):`, so the case for 0 will be auto handled.

Comment: @Satendra when I do that - the first page is ordered fine. But the next page then starts with `Two` instead of `Post`. Any idea why?

Comment: Manged to get it done by starting a counter at 1, then resetting the counter when it got to 14. Thanks for the help!